# installing debian from a local repository

Tags: debian, system-installation, repository

I have created a local repository in a debian virtual machine (I'm using virtualbox) by copying packages from iso images into the directory `/var/www/html/packages/amd64/` (apache2 is already installed) and now I'm trying to figure out how install the debian os on another machine using only the netinst iso image and my local repository.

is there a way that I can enter my local repository's address (`192.168.213.9`) during the installation instead of a debian archive mirror hostname? if not then is there a way to use `apt` to automatically install all required packages after finishing the minimal installation and modifying the `sources.list` file?

Comment: Welcome. Maybe you are looking for the TFTP boot (netbooting), [Installing Debian using network booting](https://wiki.debian.org/PXEBootInstall) and [Preparing Files for TFTP Net Booting](https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/mips/ch04s03.html.en)

Comment: You would need to set up a mirror structure under the webserver.  Alternatively, if you just have a ton of .deb files, stick them in `/target/var/cache/apt/archives` during install, or after the first boot in `/var/cache/apt/archives`.  Indexes, release files, etc. will still come from normal mirrors but deb files won't need to be re-downloaded.  If you want a real mirror, they are easy to set up using `apt-mirror`

Comment: There's more to a Debian repositories than just some packages, so you might not be able to install new hosts from what you have. In addition to doing it all manually, there exists a lot of software for maintaining a (partial) Debian mirror. I've only used it for repositories of private packages, but `aptly` should be useable for your task, and is easy to work with.

Comment: ftpsync, aptly, maybe reprepro depending on what you want to mirror. I only setup in the past TFTP boot and local repositories of my own packages. For small settings it may not be worth mirroring.

Comment: is there a way to make `apt-mirror` get packages from DVDs instead of the official website?

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit late, but I see you haven't got no answer yet. I use a local debian repository long time for security reason - my working net is strictly isolated from Internet.

On the local repository you need to take in account more files than the packages themselves. The repository does content:

- **description** of each version (even there is a single one)
- **pool** divided into *sections*: main/contrib/non-free/non-free-firmware
  (each section is divided by alphabet)

In the **description**, installer can find packages-info necessary for solving dependences.

Well configured `apt-mirror` could download all necessary files into the correct directory structure. You may access these files through web server or ftp server but also through a simple filesystem. If you had installed the basic OS (getting just cmd-line without GUI -KDE or -GNOME), you may configure your actual packages repository in file /etc/apt/sources.list, where can be:

```
deb cdrom:[name of the cd]/ bookworm main contrib
deb http://192.168.213.9/debian bookworm main contrib
deb ftp://mirror.ftp.address/debian bookworm main contrib
deb file:/path/to/local/repository/debian  bookworm main contrib
```

If using local web repository, you can specify it while installing the basic components by choosing the local mirror. If using `Expert mode`, after you just configured your network interface, you can: `Choose a mirror of the Debian archive`. You have to choose the top-most menu entry: `enter information manually`, then you wold be asked for the URI (e.g. `192.168.213.9`), then for the current `mirror directory` (e.g. /`debian`/), then for the proxy (let it empty), and at least you would be asked for the requested version (`bookworm - stable`). Than should follow the next step: `Download installer components`.

Until the stable version `bullseye` I had no problem with files downloaded with apt-mirror. The actual stable version included much more security components even necessary on the public Internet, absolutely useless on isolated local network, so the installation roars plenty of errors and warnings which I cannot understand. I hardly repaired manually a single version, and still searching the Internet for any hint or advice how to simplify this process.

I am not sure if you can simply copy files from the CD/DVD. I may try it and perhaps I will drop you a comment later.